# How to get all the hyponyms of a word/synset in python nltk and wordnet?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a list of all the nouns in wordnet now i want to leave only words which are vehicles and remove the rest. How do i do it? Below is the pseudo-code i want to make but i do not know how to make it work

```
for word in wordlist:
  if not "vehicle" in wn.synsets(word):
    wordlist.remove(word)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
vehicle = wn.synset('vehicle.n.01')
typesOfVehicles = list(set([w for s in vehicle.closure(lambda s:s.hyponyms()) for w in s.lemma_names()]))
```

This will give you all the unique words from every synset that is a [hyponym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy) of the noun "vehicle" (1st sense).

Comment: But when i try to narrow it further, i get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:...\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    if "car" in word:
TypeError: argument of type 'Synset' is not iterable

Comment: @Jared, very elegant answer but there's a `gotcha` when the `Synset.closure(lambda s:s.hyponyms()` goes to an infinite loop. Try `wn.synset('restrain.v.01').closure(lambda s:s.hyponyms()`

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable` with this method.

Comment: @StefanD This is a relatively old answer and probably does not work with the the newer versions of NLTK. If you found an alternative solution that works in newer versions, post an answer or feel free to update this answer!

Comment: User Easton commented in an answer that `lemma_names` is a method and thus parentheses should be added. Don't know if that's correct but I'm leaving it here for review by those familiar with this module.

Answer (score 9):

```
def get_hyponyms(synset):
    hyponyms = set()
    for hyponym in synset.hyponyms():
        hyponyms |= set(get_hyponyms(hyponym))
    return hyponyms | set(synset.hyponyms())
```

Comment: That works great with NLTK 3.0.3, unlike jared' answer (TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable), thanks!